# How can I configure Autoprefixer in Angular 7

Tags: angular, flexbox, prefix, autoprefixer, vendor-prefix

I'm using autoprefix in Angular 7 Project.
   But When I open the browser devtools and focus the element with class "simple-content", which has display flex as applied style, there is no expected 'prefixes'.
 In Angular 4-6 projects, this works ok.

Step 1: Run ng serve
Step 2: Open the browser devtools and focus the element with class "simple-content", which has display:flex.

In package.json I have

```
 {
    "browserslist": [
    "last 1 version",
    "> 1%"
    ]
  }. 

In package-lock.json I have 

    "autoprefixer": {
      "version": "9.4.4",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/autoprefixer/-/autoprefixer-9.4.4.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-7tpjBadJyHKf+gOJEmKhZIksWxdZCSrnKbbTJNsw+/zX9+f//DLELRQPWjjjVoDbbWlCuNRkN7RfmZwDVgWMLw==",
      "requires": {
        "browserslist": "^4.3.7",
        "caniuse-lite": "^1.0.30000926",
        "normalize-range": "^0.1.2",
        "num2fraction": "^1.2.2",
        "postcss": "^7.0.7",
        "postcss-value-parser": "^3.3.1"
      },
```

I tried to enable autoprefixing for flexbox with /* autoprefixer: on */, but no result.

In css file i have

```
.simple-content {
    display: flex;
}
```

Expected result :

```
.simple-content {
  display: -webkit-box;    
  display: -moz-box;      
  display: -ms-flexbox;   
  display: -webkit-flex;   
  display: flex;             
}
```

Comment: I think you are missing the .browserslistrc file. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-autoprefixer

Comment: Thank you. This fix the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I tried online autoprefixer tool (https://autoprefixer.github.io/) to test the browserlist you used in package.json and observed that it did not generate prefixed css:
[image: did not yield prefixed css]

On changing the browser list value to **last 2 version**, it generated autoprefixed css:
[image: did generate prefixed css]

So your package.json seems fine and you can try it by just updating browser list.

Also FYI, angular cli V7.3.5 added **src/browserslist** which means you need not to add **.browserslistrc** or **browserslist property to the package.json** for angular 7 projects. All you need to do is remove **not** on last line to support **IE 9-11**.

Comment: "angular cli v7.3.5 added src/browserslist" - I just created a new Angular project with cli version 11.0.7 and there is no browserslist

Comment: @JeneralJames it's .browserslistrc  in the root